# Grouping and Counting instances?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

Is it possible to group and count instances of all other columns using R (dplyr)? For example, The following dataframe

```
x  a  b  c
1  0  0  0
1  1  0  1
1  2  2  1
2  1  2  1
```

Turns to this (note: y is value that is being counted)

EDIT:- explaining the transformation, x is what I'm grouping by, for each number grouped, i want to count how many times 0 and 1 and 2 was mentioned, as in the first row in the transformed dataframe, we counted how many times x = 1 was equal to 0 in the other columns (y), so 0 was in column a one time, column b two times and column c one time

```
x  y  a  b  c
1  0  1  2  1
1  1  1  0  2
1  2  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  1
2  2  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a combination of `gather` and `spread` from the `tidyr` package, and `count` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df = data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,2), a = c(0,1,2,1), b = c(0,0,2,2), c = c(0,1,1,1))
res = df %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -x) %>% 
    count(x, variable, value) %>% 
    spread(variable, n, fill = 0)
# Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#
#   x value a b c
# 1 1     0 1 2 1
# 2 1     1 1 0 2
# 3 1     2 1 1 0
# 4 2     1 1 0 1
# 5 2     2 0 1 0
```

Essentially, you first change the format of the dataset to:

```
head(df %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -x))
#  x variable value
#1 1        a     0
#2 1        a     1
#3 1        a     2
#4 2        a     1
#5 1        b     0
#6 1        b     0
```

Which allows you to use `count` to get the information regarding how often certain values occur in columns `a` to `c`. After that, you reformat the dataset to your required format using `spread`.

Comment: If you like, you could add a dcast melt example yourself (and rake in some points ;)). I'm using `dplyr` a lot now, and focus on that.

Comment: It's okay.  It is the same method you showed.  So, I thought that it makes sense to add in your post.  Otherwise, I will leave it as a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

An approach with a combination of the `melt` and `dcast` functions of *data.table* or *reshape2*:

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.5+
dt.new <- dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars="x"), x + value ~ variable)
```

this gives:

```
dt.new
#    x value a b c
# 1: 1     0 1 2 1
# 2: 1     1 1 0 2
# 3: 1     2 1 1 0
# 4: 2     1 1 0 1
# 5: 2     2 0 1 0
```

In `dcast` you can specify which aggregation function to use, but this is in this case not necessary as the default aggregation function is `length`. Without using an aggregation function, you will get a warning about that:

> Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length

Furthermore, if you do not explicitly convert the dataframe to a data table, `data.table` will redirect to `reshape2` (see the explanation from @Arun in the comments). Consequently this method can be used with `reshape2` as well:

```
library(reshape2)
df.new <- dcast(melt(df, id.vars="x"), x + value ~ variable)
```

---

**Used data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="x  a  b  c
1  0  0  0
1  1  0  1
1  2  2  1
2  1  2  1", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I always thought `dcast` came from `reshape2`, and not `data.table`. Or does `data.table` provide specfic implementations of `dcast` (as it is a generic function). In that case, shouldn't we need to cast `df` to some kind of `data.table` format first?

Comment: @PaulHiemstra The latest version of `data.table` now also [includes its own implementations of the `melt` and `dcast` functions](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html). At first I also thought you would need to use `setDT()`, but apparently this is not necessary and it also works on dataframes (which I off course tried before posting ;-) ).

Comment: Unless you convert to data table the data table methods are not used.

Comment: @Arun I thought that as well, but when I have `data.table` loaded it appears to work on dataframes as well (without having `reshape2` loaded). When I detach `data.table`, i get an error message: *Error: could not find function "dcast"*.

Comment: Data table redirects to reshape2 if the object isn't a data table. Check data.table::dcast

Comment: @Arun Didn't know that. Changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks for the note.  (+1).  The same code works with `reshape2`  also. `dcast(melt(df, id.vars='x'), x+value~variable)`

Comment: @akrun true, added it to my answer